# How do I conditionally pass a constructor to a base class?

Tags: c#, constructor

Say I have a class like so:

```
public class A : B
{
   private static default_i = 42;
   public A(int? i): B(i){}
}
```

Can I/How do I conditionally initialize B with default_i, when i is null?

Comment: To be complete, post the constructor(s) of B.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
public A(int? i): base(i ?? A.default_i) {}
```

Comment: instead of `B` it should be `base`, +1 though